# Оправка данных в шаблонизатор

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Как из двух запросов сформировать один объект и отрендерить шаблон? Аргументы в callback функции доступны только в рамках тело функции, как их можно вынести на уровень выше. return не работает.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => { 

    Client.find({}, (err, docs) => {
        res.render('index', docs[0]);
    });

    Equipment.find({}, (err, docsEquip)=> {
        res.render('index', docsEquip[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
     Client.find({}, (err, docs) => {
        Equipment.find({}, (err, docsEquip)=> {
            res.render('index', {docs:docs[0], docsEquip:docsEquip[0]});
        })
    });
});
```